# Difference between returning a Task and using async/await

Tags: .net-core, async-await

Consider this asynchronous method:

```
public async Task<Data> AnotherMethodAsync()
{
    var reader = await GetData();
    reeturn Convert(reader);
}
```

Now I want to call this from another method. If the call is a simple call through or no work is being done after the call, what is the difference between these two examples:

**Return Task**

```
public Task<Data> SomeMethodAsync()
{
    return AnotherMotherAsync();
}
```

**Async/Await**

```
public async Task<Data> SomeMethodAsync()
{
    await AnotherMotherAsync();
}
```

Is the one more correct than the other? Is there any performance considerations?

Comment: If you don't need to await the response then the task should be fire and forget. Use `Task.Run(() => x)`

Comment: Well maybe there are others calling `SomeMethodAsync` which need to await that.

Comment: @ESG Yes, I think the [MSDN article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2011/october/asynchronous-programming-async-performance-understanding-the-costs-of-async-and-await). Better start reading :) Basically I want to understand what is going on underneath in the two different scenarios.

Comment: I have a [blog post on the subject](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html).